# XML attributes searching some STRING

Tags: php, xml, json

Can anyone help me.
basically I have XML file

```
<AB NAME="A Quick Brown">
    ..some multiple node inside here
</AB>
<AB NAME="Fox Jumps Over">
    ..some multiple node inside here
</AB>
<AB NAME="The Lazy Dog">
    ..some multiple node inside here
</AB>
<AB NAME="The Quickbox">
    ..some multiple node inside here
</AB>
```

I need to search a String on attributes of `<AB>`
to search the whole and equally TRUE string this ex. will work

```
$string = "A Quick Brown";
$result = $xml->xpath("AB[@NAME ='$string']");
```

but what I need to search is only the `"Quick"` word for example

```
  $string = "Quick";
 // $result = $xml->xpath("AB[@NAME ='$string']");
```

in attributes of AB so that I will get only the

```
<AB NAME="Fox Jumps Over">
    ..some multiple node inside here
</AB>
```

part of my xml. 
Any suggestion, and Comment is well appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at using [`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) in the query.

```
AB[contains(@NAME, 'Quick')]
```

Comment: oh, maybe this is the key. I will try it now. Thanks Sir

Comment: @kodewrecker salathe is right but use `//` if you have a complex xml document and your AB nodes are not at a root level.

Comment: that will works fine thanks to @salathe Im about to search for xpath manual that's why. sorry for silly question.

But 1 more thing what if I have another node <AB name='Quick'>..some  multiple node <AB> what would be my result?